# Como remover redirecionamento do htaccess para a pasta public

Tags: php, htaccess, ssl, https

As configurações do meu `htaccess` para forçar o `SSL` esta da seguinte forma:

```
# NA PASTA RAIZ

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> <br>
RewriteEngine on<br>
<br><br>
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L] <br>
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]<br>
</IfModule><br>

# NA PASTA PUBLIC

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

mais quando vai fazer o redirecionamento do SSL a url vem o seguinte

```
https://www.meusite.com/public
```

ou

```
https://www.meusite.com/public/index.php
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso para a pasta `public` e `index.php` não aparecer na `url`?

Comment: se não me engano você precisa usar `RewriteBase /public/` ou assim `RewriteBase /public`

Comment: pior que nao , já tente assim e deu a mesma coisa :/

Comment: acho que isso te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973058/how-to-remove-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: é Hebert de Lima deu certo não, as configurações da hospedagem que estou usando é bem rigida e nao deixa alterar muita coisa

Comment: #RESOLVIDO

# remover pasta public/ do redirecionamento
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+/)?public/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]